# Image beside text - image at top, text one line to multirow - what is best practise?

Tags: graphics, floats, minipage

I would like to place small images that align to top with respect to text and beside it a text - sometimes one line, sometimes multirow. I use figures and minipages now to place it. Is there a simpler solution f.e. without using floats?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}
\centering
\vspace{5pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{icon-panacek.png}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.3cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{8.5cm}
\vspace{5pt}
5 - 99 roků\\
\noindent\color{cadetgrey}\rule[3pt]{9cm}{0.1pt}
\end{minipage}% 
\begin{figure}[!h]
\hspace{0.5cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.5cm}
\centering
\vspace{5pt}
\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{icon-panacek.png}
\end{minipage}%
\hspace{0.3cm}
\begin{minipage}[t]{8.5cm}
\vspace{5pt}
5 - 99 roků\\
\noindent\color{cadetgrey}\rule[3pt]{9cm}{0.1pt}
\end{minipage}%
```

[image: showcase]

Comment: Since you asked for a solution without floats: You can remove the `figure` environment as it is not needed in your example.

Comment: Thank you for a good hint. I consider the question answered if you please post an answer.